# Arrange filter values in tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I Have Filter Values (dimension) in Tableau - that I want to arrange in ascending order.

The values in the quick filter are currently ordered alphabetically:

```
03 to 05-Jun-2015
06 to 10-Jul-2015
08 to 12-Jun-2015
13 to 16-Jul-2015
15 to 19-Jun-2015
20 to 24-Jul-2015
22 to 26-Jul-2015
27 to 31-Jul-2015
29 to 03-Jul-2015
```

In the list above, values are ordered alphabetically, not chronologically.  I want them to be in this order:

```
03 to 05-Jun-2015
08 to 12-Jun-2015
15 to 19-Jun-2015
06 to 10-Jul-2015
13 to 16-Jul-2015
20 to 24-Jul-2015
22 to 26-Jul-2015
27 to 31-Jul-2015
29 to 03-Jul-2015
```

Is there a way to make the above filter values display in the desired order?

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to apply a manual sort order from the sort panel (which you can bring up by right clicking on the dimension you wish to sort, either on the data pane to set a default sort order, or on a shelf to set a sort order for one worksheet)

If you don't want a manual sort order, you can apply a dynamic sort based on the values in the data from the same panel, or use the database default sort order (usually alphabetic order).

In that last case, you probably want to use a standard easily sorted convention for your field values -- say ISO 9001 dates like YYYY-MM-DD, perhaps following by a duration length in days, say YYYY-MM-DD (n)

Alternatively, if you could change the data type of the field from string to date, say called start_date, then you would get sorting by default and many options for filter controls.

Comment: The values are dynamic, it keeps changing. So i am not sure about manual sort order

Comment: Then I would name the values in a way that supports easy sorting. ISO-9001 format for dates sorts easily YYYY-MM-DD. How about YYYY-MM-DD (n) ? where n is the duration in days of the interval, and YYYY-MM-DD is the start of the interval.